# Customize incoming call screen in android

Tags: android

Is is possible to display custom incoming call screen instead of default one in android?

Actually, I  have worked on the issue for more than over 10 days. Now, my application receives incoming calls and the activity showing my custom incoming call screen appears. However, the problem is that the default one is always on the top.I am not able neither to hide it below my activity nor to disable it. So that only my activity is on the tap

Comment: you can open any activity in transparent mode during incoming or outgoing calls. that's the best workaround AFAIK.

Comment: Not unless you customize the firmware. The default incoming call screen has system privileges and can display itself over all other activities.